# Post-запрос к вконтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Заливаю фотографию во вконтакте, постоянно получаю пустой `photos_list`:

> {"server":317823,"photos_list":"[]","aid":114599239,"hash":"3eba9315fef6c796e861d926911993c7"}

Что я делаю не так? Какие-то особые `header` надо прописать?

```
$url = урл, который вернул photos.getUploadServer 
$data = file_get_contents("photo.jpg");

    function post_req($url, $data){

        $data = array('file1' => $data);
        $options = array('http' => array(   
            'method'  => 'POST',  
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;",
            'content' => http_build_query($data)));

        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        print_r($result);   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Загружать фотографии надо файлом изображения, то есть например заранее передать его c multipart/form-data, затем передавать в качестве файла. Надеюсь, что понятно объяснил.

А вообще, пользуйтесь [vk.api.class.php](http://vk.com/source/APIServerPHPClass.zip), это намного приятней и сокращает код :)

Answer (score 0):

когда в ответ приходит пустой фотослист это значит ни что иное как то, что никаких фотографий ты не пытаешься загрузить. попробуй так

```
//здесь у нас массив фоток,который ты пытаешься загрузить на сервер, если нужна одна то грузи одну
$post_params = array(
"file1" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image1.jpg",
"file2" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image2.jpg",
"file3" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image3.jpg",
"file4" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image4.jpg",
"file5" => "@".dirname(__FILE__)."/itmp/image5.jpg"
);
//проверяешь постпарамс есть ли он вообще, тока расскамментируй
//  var_dump($post_params);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);   
// проверяешь что у тебя в ресалте.


//  var_dump($result);
```

P.S. код полностью 10500% рабочий